# Handling callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am working on a node.js project in which I need to communicate with a mongoDb database. I am currently programming a function to find some data in my db using th node-mongodb-native module. Everything works, but my code looks like a callback in a callback in a callback in a callback...
I created this function to prevent me from using callbacks every time I want to access my database. I now just need to call this function.

```
module.exports.find = function(query, projection, callback){
    db.open(function(err, db){
        if(err) throw err;
        db.collection('rooms', function(err, collection){
            if(err) throw err;
            collection.find(query, projection, function(err, cursor){
                if (err) throw err;
                cursor.toArray(function(err, find){
                    db.close();
                    callback(err, find);
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Is there a method to reduce this *codeception* ?

Comment: take a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: Why you don't declare a variable in your main function and assign db, collection and cursor to them and immediately return from your inner-callbacks! this way you can avoid callback-in-callback.

Comment: @Boynux, like this : `var database = db.open(function(err, db){
        if(err) throw err;
        return db;
    });` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
module.exports.find = function(query, projection, callback){
    var database;

    db.open(function(err, db_temp){
        if(err) throw err;

        database = db_temp;
    });

    database.collection('rooms', function(err, collection){
        if(err) throw err;
        collection.find(query, projection, function(err, cursor){
            if (err) throw err;
            cursor.toArray(function(err, find){
                db.close();
                callback(err, find);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: That doesn't look much better and relies on `.open` being synchronous

Comment: I tester your code and it throws an error : Cannot call method 'open' of undefined. After I changed the `var db;` for `var database` and `database.collection(`, but now ti throws : Cannot call method 'collection' of undefined

Comment: oh! sorry, may bad! yes of course, i'll fix it!

Comment: Oh, and finally, would you recommend using async.waterfall or this technique?

Comment: Sorry, I've no experience with that! Some googling may help :)
BTW, you can extend this method to collection too!

Comment: I'll do that, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know how to cleanup callbacks reasonably and scope db:

```
module.exports.find = function(query, projection, callback){
    var local_db;

    function db_open(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;
        local_db = db;
        local_db.collection('rooms', handle_homes_collection);

    }

    function handle_homes_collection(err, collection){
        if(err) throw err;
        collection.find(query, projection, handle_find_query);
    }

    function handle_find_query(err, cursor){
        if (err) throw err;
        cursor.toArray(function(err, find){
            local_db.close();
            callback(err, find);
        });
    }

    db.open(db_open);
};
```

Comment: +1: Giving each function a name is also a very good way of documenting what it does. There is a place for anonymous functions but I think if you're nesting more than one level deep you need to name them ;)

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I just needed to change the `db.open` by another variable name (`database.open`) because it returned `Cannot call method 'open' of undefined`, but after this little edit it worked :)